# Menu li add and remove class

Tags: jquery, html

I have this menu:

```
<ul id="mainmenu" class="nav menu sf-menu responsive-menu superfish">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="search.php">Search</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="search.php">Browse</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this tiny script:\

```
var selector = '#mainmenu li';
$(selector).on('click', function() {
    $(selector).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

What I want is, when the page loads for the first time `home` to be the active link. Then when the user navigates on another page, the `active` class to be applied to the clicked `li`. The problem is that when I click on another `li` the class is added, and then quickly removed. What may be the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: What is your CSS styling? I'd guess you're applying the style to the `li`, but it's being overridden by something on the `a`

Comment: use toggleClass instead of adding and removing

Comment: are you refreshing your page when you click on main menu

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when you click an element, you get redirected, and the page is rendered again.

```js
var selector = '#mainmenu li';
$(selector).on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(selector).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

try to disable the  redirect event to confirm this.

Comment: How do I go on another page if I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just going off the details you've provided, I'm assuming you haven't got AJAX loading pages, so when you click on the link, yes the class gets added and then you are taken to the different page loaded fresh.

There's no real way of achieving what you want in javascript unless you load in the external links through AJAX and I can't really provide a working code sample for you because it's rarely a one case fits all.

http://api.jquery.com/load/ might be something you're interested in. It allows you to load an external page into an element (i.e your main content element)

Answer (score 0):

The redirect made the script (if i can say) 'ephemeral' cause the script is loaded in the first page then in the second which don't know wich link has been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

When you clicked on a link it loads a new page always and remove your added class. The following code snippet will solve your problem.

```
 var pgurl = window.location.href;
 $("#mainmenu li a").each(function(){
      $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
      if(pgurl.indexOf($(this).attr("href"))>-1){
          $(this).addClass("active");
      }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Page gets refreshed after you click the link. Try to add active class to li based on its href.

Sample code :

```
         var url = window.location;

    jQuery('a[href="'+url+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
```